# Get all custom DOM properties

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dom

I am attaching DOM properties to an element dynamically like so:

```
i = 0;
document.body['a' + i] = "foo";
document.body['b' + i] = "bar";
```

Is there a way I can get all of those properties that I attached as an array? Example:

```
var allProperties = ['a0', 'b0'];
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want the key or the value? By that I mean, would you like the array to be ["foo","bar"] or ['a0','b0']?

Comment: @MarkWalters I don't want to use global arrays.

Comment: @AlexMorrise If I have the key I can call the value, so only the key would be enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can actually create a new body object, and compare against that object to get properties not added by the browser

```
i = 0;
document.body['a' + i] = "foo";
document.body['b' + i] = "bar";

var el  = document.createElement('body'),
    arr = [];

for (var key in document.body) {
    if (document.body.hasOwnProperty(key) && !(key in el)) {
        arr.push(key);
    }
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/zzL5N/)

being a little more fancy

```
var el  = document.createElement('body'),
    arr = Object.keys(document.body).filter(function(prop) {
        return !(prop in el);
    });
```

Comment: Nice one! completely sidesteps the need to keep a separate array of properties added. At the same time it will report properties that may be set for the initial body

Comment: @samy - It would return all properties not natively set by the browser, so anything added later, at any time, would be returned, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Add a property with a fixed name to the element you're interested in, and push the custom properties

```
var pushInto = function(element, name, value)
{
    element[name] = value;
    if (element["customProperties"] == undefined)
    {
         element["customProperties"] = [];
    }
    element["customProperties"].push(name);
}
```

Then you can do :

```
pushInto(document.body, "name", "value");
document.body["customProperties"]; // ["name"]
```